# Passing variable database name in psycopg2's execute()

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

This is what I have:

```
    db_name = 'temp_test_database'
    conn.set_isolation_level(0)
    cursor.execute('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS {}'.format(db_name))
```

This functionality works and does what I expect, but violates the parameter passing [rule](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#sql-injection).

I have looked at [SQL string composition documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql), but this doesn't work with database names. It wraps it with "Identifier()", which breaks.

Is there "clean" way to dynamically set the database in a psycopg2 execute call?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`psycopg2.sql.Identifier`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.Identifier) and compose the SQL statement like so:

```
from from psycopg2 import sql

cursor.execute(sql.SQL("drop database if exists {}")
    .format(sql.Identifier(db_name)))
```

The whole linked documentation page is worth a read.

Comment: This generates malformed SQL  

psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "("  
LINE 1: DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS Identifier('temp_test_database')

Answer (score 0):

The trick was using `as_string()` using the cursor as context. See the [docs about this method](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html#psycopg2.sql.Composable.as_string).

Here you a have a complete working snippet:

```py
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="postgres")
conn.set_isolation_level(0)
cursor = conn.cursor()
db_name = sql.Identifier("temp_test_database").as_string(cursor)
cursor.execute('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS {}'.format(db_name))
...
```